# smarty tags and css condition tags are the same,what is the solution?

Tags: conditional-statements, smarty, css

i want to design a theme for postnuke cms.

and want to use css condition in the template files.

postnuke use smarty tag like

```
<!--[if $n eq ''] -->....<!--[/if]-->
```

so when i use

```
<!--[if lt IE 7]>....<![endif]-->
```

it gives some errors about tags.
what can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping your if comments in literal tags, in the smarty .tpl file.

```
{literal}
<!--[if lt IE 7]>....<![endif]-->
{/literal}
```

Might fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I've had problem with IE conditionals in smarty templates (.tpl). My smarty version is 2.6.26. I'm using PHP 5.5.11. I've just looked into source and try few adjustments of wrong syntax proposed on smarty forums or other pages :)

That's working for me:

```
{literal}
    <!--[if IE 7]-->
    <style> 
        .delete {
            top: -1px;
        }
        .comment_input {
            max-width: 85% !important;
            width: 85% !important;
        }
    </style>
    <!--[endif]-->
{/literal}
```

Regards,
Jan